# jQuery fadeIn div when input is in focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the innerHTML of a div and fade it in when a input in my form comes into focus. I also want to test whether or not it's been faded in at all because when the page loads it will begin faded out.

To summarize, I essentially want to display a tooltip in another div and switch the tooltip with fading in and out as my inputs come into focus on my form.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var visible = 0;
var nameText = "<p>May I get your<br/>full name?</p>";
var emailText = "<p>Could I please<br/>get your email<br/>address?</p>";
var messageText = "<p>What is the<br/>message you<br/>would like to send?</p>";

$('.inp').on("focus", function(event){
    if (visible == 0)
    {
        var fadeTime = 1;
        visible = 1;
    }
    else
        fadeTime = 500;

    $('bubble').fadeOut(fadeTime).html(function() {
        if ($this.attr('id') == "name")
            return nameText;
        else if ($this.attr('id') == "email")
            return emailText;
        else if ($this.attr('id') == "message")
            return messageText;
    }).fadeIn(500);

});
</script>
```

I'm not receiving any JavaScript errors. My HTML for my bubble and inputs looks like this:

```
<footer class="container">
<div class="row reveal">
    <div class="mailman fourcol">
        <img src="images/mailman.png" alt="The Mail Man" />
        <div id="bubble">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact eightcol last">

        <h1>CONTACT US FOR</h1> <h1>MORE INFORMATION</h1>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <form name="contact-form">

            <div class="form-left">

                <div class="contact-name inp">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Name" />
                </div>

                <div class="contact-email inp">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Email" />
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="contact-message inp">
                    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" value="Message" />
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="contact-submit">
                <a href=""></a>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: a `div` cannot have `focus`, thus your function will never get called. Try applying the handler for `focus` to the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some fix to you. ***[Check the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/RMaat/)***

The main problems are:

1. focus event should be fired on input element, `$('.inp').on("focus", function(event){` should be `$('.inp').on("focus", 'input', function(event){`
2. `$this.attr(id)`, you missed `var $this = $(this);` outside, or just use `var id = this.id;`.
3. `$('bubble')` should be `$(#bubble)`

Comment: Great! The fading appears to be working. The last thing is that I'll only need to change the text after the element has faded out. I believe I can fix that from this point.

I appreciate the response!